# Set radio button state based on a value received from REST in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

What I would like to achieve is set a radio button's state according to the data retrieved from the server in AngularJS.

What makes this more special is that I need to show a div based on a condition (the car has 1 and only 1 assigned to it).
If the car is so-called `isSingleUser`, the div contains the radio buttons needs to be visible, otherwise we need to hide it.

Finally, after a lot of struggling, I even have the solution to achieve this, but I ran into some interesting obstacles what I want to share with others for reference and I still have some questions regarding the alternative "solutions".

1. **The simplest (and working) solution**

   We have 3 cars, the Cars service will GET the particular car according to the chosen link.
   Only car1 and car2 are `isSingleUser` so the div should only visible for those cars.
   You can see that the radio button's state changes according to the
   `car.isMonitoringAutoEnablementSet` JSON property.
   This was my first attempt, but I couldn't see the code working at that time, I used the 
   value property of the input, wrongly, because the ng-value is better.

   More specifically, the `value` property on input cannot handle boolean values as booleans (and not stringified)
   therefore angular couldn't map the boolean value `false` to `"false"` and the same goes with the `true` value.
   If I used `ng-value`, everything is fine.
   Note that the plateNumber for each car is visible on the page.

   Let's see what I tried afterwards:
2. **Magic with promise**

   My assumption was that the data for car is not downloaded yet and the template rendered
   before the controller received the data and store it to `$scope.car`

   So I added this code for the controller:

   ```
   $scope.car = Cars.get({carId: $routeParams.carId})
       .$promise.then(function(car) {
             $scope.automonitoring_state = car.isMonitoringAutoEnablementSet;
             $scope.isSingleUser = car.isSingleUser;
        });
   ```

   and modified the view according to the new variables:

   ```
   <h1 class="title">{{car.plateNumber}}</h1>
     <div class='ng-hide' ng-show='isSingleUser'>
       <p class='paragraph'>automatic
         <form name="myForm" class="toggle">
           <input type="radio" name="state" ng-model="automonitoring_state" ng-value="true">on
           <input type="radio" name="state" ng-model="automonitoring_state" ng-value="false">off
           <button class="button" disabled>save</button>
         </form>
       </p>
     </div>
   ```

   Note that the plateNumbers are disappeared from the page, clearly showing that some problem
   occured while fetching the data for the `car` variable. Only the new variables had a
   value in the `scope` (`automonitoring_state` and `isSingleUser`).
   Somehow even if I put a simple `console.log()` inside the then function on the promise, the
   `car` variable will not hold the data for the car, strange...
   This solution also seems like a workaround, because I need to define new variables in the
   `scope`, but if I save the car's state through the service, I need to sync back my new
   variables to the `$scope.car` so this one is definitely a no-go for me.
3. **Resolve with the help of a controller scope function**

   Then I googled and googled, found some advices on Stackoverflow, and so on.
   Hey, there is `resolve` which is good for passing some variables into controllers before the view is rendered, that's exactly what I want. 
   Naively, I tried to invoke a controller function from the `routeProvider` like this :

   ```
   when('/driver/cars/:carId', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/driver_car.html',
     controller: 'DriverCarController',
     resolve: 'DriverCarController'.resolveCar
   })
   ```

   and of course added the function in question to the controller:

   ```
   $scope.resolveCar = {
           car: ['$routeParams', 'Cars',
               function($routeParams, Cars) {
                   return Cars.get({
                       carId: $routeParams.carId
                   }).then(function(car) {
                       console.log('resolve');
                       return car;
                   }, function() {
                       return [];
                   });
               }
           ]
   };
   ```

   The result is: nothing, no `console.log` at all, proving that the function was not invoked.
4. **Another working solution with passing the variable from resolve**
   This trial is a slightly modified version of the solution above.
   The `Cars` service is only used from the `$routeProvider`, if the promise returns the value, it is saved to the `car` variable.

   ```
   .when('/driver/cars/:carId', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/driver_car.html',
     controller: 'DriverCarController',
     resolve: {
     car : function (Cars,$route) {
         return Cars.get({carId: $route.current.params.carId})
               .$promise.then(function (response) {
                  return response;
               });
             }
           }
   })
   ```

   The only thing to change in the controller is to add `'car'` to the injection list and save
   the parameter to the `$scope`.

   ```
   controllers.controller('DriverCarController', ['$scope', '$routeParams','car', 'SecurityEvents',
     function($scope, $routeParams, car, SecurityEvents) {
       $scope.car = car;
       console.log(car);
     }
   ]);
   ```

Please see my public plunkers, you can try out each solution I described above: [plunkers](http://plnkr.co/users/szyszy)

Any help is appreciated about judging between the most viable approach, providing some information about the intended use cases of each alternative.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 is the most similar to what I have used.

To fix the bug, just change the code in the controller like this:

```
Cars.get({
   carId: $routeParams.carId
}).$promise.then(function(car) {
     $scope.automonitoring_state = car.isMonitoringAutoEnablementSet;
     $scope.isSingleUser = car.isSingleUser;
     $scope.car = car;
});
```

The biggest problem that I see with calling the service from the resolve is that it tightly couples the controller with the app router, which means your controller is less re-useable.